# Can't understand nasm error. How to fix code.

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I try to call printf function from asm code.

hello.asm:

```
%macro exit 0
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
%endmacro

extern   printf      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data
    hello:     db   'Hello world!', 0

SECTION .text
    GLOBAL main

main:
    sub 8, rsp
    push dword hello
    call printf      ; Call C function
    add 8, rsp
    exit
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
    ld hello.o -e main -o hello -lc -I/lib/ld-linux.so.2

clean:
    rm -f hello.o hello
```

make call:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
hello.asm:16: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
hello.asm:19: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Please explain errors and how to fix code.

Thanks.

Comment: You have your operands backwards for `sub` and `add`.  Intel syntax is `add dst, src`, so you use `sub rsp, 8`.  Did you translate from AT&T syntax and miss that?

Comment: Also, if you are using 64bit code (as indicated by RSP), you shouldn't be using int 80, but `syscall`, which also uses different registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes yep. I fixed it, now I receive error bash: ./hello: Accessing a corrupted shared library

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Yes, but it will still work (on most systems) for system calls that don't need 64-bit inputs (like pointers) ([What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)).  More importantly for this case, the x86-64 System V calling convention doesn't pass args on the stack.  It should be `mov edi, hello` or `lea rdi, [rel hello]`.  [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212).

Comment: @e42d3: link with gcc, it knows how to pass the right args.  `gcc -v -nostartfiles -no-pie hello.o`.  (`-v` prints the actual linker command it used, in case you're curious). And don't use `-e main`, call your entry point `_start`.  (And don't mess with RSP, it's already 16-byte aligned at the ELF entry point, unlike at `main`.  Or better, leave out `-nostartfiles` so the normal startup stuff runs before main, instead of depending on dynamic linker stuff to initialize libc before you call stdio functions.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Who was it that said [syscall system calls are faster than int 0x80 system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/2189500)?  Or pointed out that passing pointers to string constants (as OP is doing) may not work for [position-independent executables, which many Linux distros now configure gcc to make by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731/2189500).  Such being the case I feel comfortable saying that using int 0x80 is a bad habit to get into on x64.  Clearly OP has other problems. But discouraging int 0x80 from x64 still seems appropriate.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: yeah, IDK why I bothered to disagree about that.  It's basically fine for `sys_exit` if you're writing a microbenchmark that can assemble as 32-bit or 64-bit code, but that's about the only good use-case for `int 0x80` in 64-bit code.  I guess I was thinking that pointing out the actual bugs that would stop it from working should be done first.  (And `sys_exit` after a stdio function is a potential bug no matter what ABI you use, because stdout is full-buffered if redirected to a file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

hello.c:

```
extern exit      ; the C function, to be called
extern puts      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data
    hello:     db   'Hello world!', 0

SECTION .text
    GLOBAL _start

_start:
    mov edi, hello
    call puts      ; Call C function
    mov edi, 0
    call exit      ; Call C function
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
    gcc -nostartfiles -no-pie hello.o -o hello

clean:
    rm -f hello.o hello
```

Comment: Your push/pop misaligns the stack.  It's already 16-byte aligned on entry to `_start`, unlike on entry to a function.  (`_start` isn't a function, that's why you can't `ret` from it.)  Also, you're still using the 32-bit ABI for sys_exit.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thank you.

Comment: You still didn't fix the alignment bug.  `puts` is allowed to crash if you call it like this.  The version you're using just happens not to use any `movaps` instructions to copy stuff to/from the stack.  I'd upvote if you fixed that.  Using libc `exit(3)` instead of the system call is a good thing, though.  It makes your program  flush stdio buffers before exiting, so it still works if you redirect output to a file.  So that is better than just switching to `mov eax,231` / `syscall`.

Answer (score 3):

Both error messages give good clues. They happen in lines 16 and 19.

In line 16 you have:

```
sub 8, rsp
```

The problem here is that you cannot subtract (anything) from a literal constant. I think that the actual intention was

```
sub rsp, 8
```

Similarly for line 19. Instead of

```
add 8, rsp
```

what you want is

```
add rsp, 8
```

Take in account that for instructions such as `sub` and `add`, the first operand acquires the result of the operation. And literal constants cannot do that!

Comment: Also for better understanding, I think it's good to add here that NASM usually takes instructions in the way `op dest, src` whereas `op` is the operation, `dest` the destination and `src` the source. So `add esp, 8` equals to `esp += 8` in the C syntax.